# my code is not throwing any packets in the console window

Tags: python, sockets, networking

I have a correct code. Everything seems okay but it is not capturing any data packets:

```
UDP_PORT = 0

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, # Internet
                     socket.SOCK_DGRAM ) # UDP

sock.bind(('', 0))
print("waiting on port:", UDP_PORT)
while True:
   data, addr = sock.recvfrom(65565)  # buffer size is 1024 bytes

print ("received message:", data)
```

Comment: Are you sure that you want to use the port 0?

Comment: I got it, on that port no data packets were coming